# Google APIs OAuth2 Certificate Blocked

Tags: java, google-signin, google-oauth

I'm currently doing some work for a client in Angular & Java Spring Boot, but I am coming across an error that I've not experienced on any other client's infrastructure.

I'm implemented Google Sign-In with backend verification, but when using the `GoogleIdTokenVerifier` class method `verify`, I am getting the following error when trying to get the remote signing key:

`sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Debugging my application, it seems that I cannot connect to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

I have verified that the application works outside of my client's organisation.

I have Googled the error, and come across lots of articles claiming that I need to add the relevant certificates to the Key Chain, but I have tried this in several ways without any joy. I have also ensured that all of the required proxy configuration has been done correctly.

Has anyone experience an issue like this before and able to offer any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Is that the correct URL?  Shouldn't it be: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs?

Either way, it would probably make sense to open the URL in a browser and check the details of the digital certificate.  A lot of companies use a transparent proxy which will re-encode the page with their own cert.  In which case you have to add that you your truststore.

Comment: @AndyN , absolutely, my apologies, I have no idea how that rubbish got in my clipboard. I have updated the post. However yes, the link points to two certificates, hosted at a location with a third certificate. I have installed all three of these and added them to my truststore with no joy!

Comment: No - my guess was that the error was coming from accessing the URL itself.  Open it in your browser and check the issuer.  (In Chrome: Padlock icon -> Certificate -> Details).  Is the issuer Google or is it one created by your company?

Comment: Oh snap, yea the issuers are different when I access the URL on their infrastructure compared to off their network.

Comment: Cool.  Let me know if that works and I'll add it as an answer.  A lot of the time enterprise deployment solutions will come with the company certs pre-installed (and maintained).  Might be worth you asking around to see if there's an easy way to do this at your company.

Comment: share your code which is failing that will help to locate the problem